# Which is better practice: fewer IF statements with more data, or the other way around?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm coding a program that switches certain parts of a report's information depending on the group that the document belongs into. So, there are a lot of if statements. A lot of them.

Now I've been wondering which would be better practice:

```
If documentGroup = "34" Then
    fillThisInfo
End If
"Here is text that's part of every document."
If documentGroup = "34" And documentID = "C321" Then
    fillThisInfoInToo
End If
```

Or

```
If documentGroup = "34" Then
    fillThisInfo + "Here is text that's part of every document."
    If documentID = "C321" Then
    fillThisInfoInToo
    End If
End If
```

I was wondering, which is worse performance-wise: Repeating and thus adding more data inside the code, or using several if statements and trying to "recycle" as much data as possible?

Comment: These are not the same. Former approach adds `Here is text that's part of every document.` to any document while the latter adds it to documents from group 34.

Comment: ^^As said above. Though in general you want to re-use code where possible and reduce repetition.

Comment: @Xaqron that was my point, exactly. I guess I didn't word it well enough. I meant that is it better to make only a few if statements that contain the same data, as in text, in this case, or make several if statements, trying to recycle the text that belongs to all the document groups? I've read from several sources that piling if statements inside code is bad practice, but then again it feels a little dumb to include the same information in every piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about performance: This stuff happens so fast that you have to iterate maybe a million time to see a difference. Accessing the Office Objects is slow, but things in memory is usually executed in no time.

What you should care about is readability and maintainability of your code. Is it easier to follow the logic of your code having several `If`'s or with an if within an if?
Take care about that you don't put same code twice in your program. For example, in the 2nd version you would need an `else` write the *"Here is text that's part of every document."* information if you are not in the `34` case. - avoid that if possible.

What I would strongly advice is to get rid of these *magic number* (eg `"34"`). Define a constant with a meaningful name: `Const MySpecialDocumentGroup = "34"`. And: Indent your code! In your second example, you have an `If` within an `If` - Indent the call to `fillThisInfoInToo` with one more tab.

Comment: Oh, alright! I wasn't aware that it doesn't actually make a difference in performance. I'll start focusing on the readability then. And no, if I would add the part inside an "Else" statement then it wouldn't appear in the "34" version of the document - hence the written "text that's part of every document." Also, these were just examples, not actual pieces of my code. I aim to give meaningful names and I do intend my code - I just got a little lazy here with all the space presses - sorry!